# Content search - An error has occurred and the search cannot be completed

Tags: solr, content-search

When I search something in the Content search and it is not working, and the UI shows 0 results with a message on red background under the search bar *"An error has occurred and the search cannot be completed."*

The logs are showing the following message:

> 12712 12:04:10 WARN  Could not map index document (field: item_ut_us_t; Value: <link linktype="internal" url="/Home/Collection it) - Parameter count mismatch.
> Exception: System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException
> Message: Parameter count mismatch.
> Source: mscorlib
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object value, Object[] index)
> at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.SetProperty(Object obj, PropertyInfo property, Object value)
> at Sitecore.ContentSearch.DocumentTypeMapInfo.SetProperty(Object target, String propertyName, String documentFieldName, Object value)
> at Sitecore.ContentSearch.DefaultDocumentMapper1.MapFieldValuesToType[TElement](IDictionary2 fieldValues, TElement result, DocumentTypeMapInfo documentTypeMapInfo)

In some cases, the logs show:

> Could not map index document (field: item_ut_us_t; Value: <link
> id="{B29EBCE5-9E9E-4073-A503-900437724D28}" )

instead of above, but the rest is the same.

There are no other logs that can help me and I'm new with Solr. Any hints and tips that I can use are more than welcome.

Comment: Could you please paste search code, related to item_ut_us_t?

Comment: Hi, have you tried to repopulate Index schema and rebuild index? Do you have errors when performing this?